# How to fetch the image using JSON in ListFragment?

Tags: android, json

I am new to android development,I am parsing my data using JSON Parsing method,I extend my class with List Fragment and I want my data in list view but the problem is i am getting all the data perfectly except the images,i don't know how to solve it,my response looks like this

```
 {"matching":[{"name":"Monic Dano","profile_id":"GM335695","image":"http://mywebsitename.com/images/Girlnoimage.jpg","cast":"","age":"24","location":"Ivory Coast"}]}
```

[image: here is my logcat output]
[image: see my output is look like this and i am not getting images]

```
public class HomeFragment extends ListFragment {

    //CustomAdapter adapter;
    //private List<RowItem> rowItems;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    //JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    JSONArray matching=null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> aList;
    private static String MATCH_URL = null;
    private static final String TAG_MATCH="matching";
    private static final String TAG_NAME="name";
    private static final String TAG_PROFILE="profile_id";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE="image";
    private static final String TAG_CAST="cast";
    private static final String TAG_AGE="age";
    private static final String TAG_LOCATION="location";

    private ListView listview;

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String strtext = getArguments().getString("user_login_id");
         MATCH_URL = "http://mywebsitename.com/webservice/matching?version=apps&user_login_id="+strtext;
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

       // rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

        listview=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        new LoadAlbums().execute();



        return rootView;
    }

    class LoadAlbums extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeFragment.this.getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(MATCH_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    matching = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_MATCH);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < matching.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = matching.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item values in variable
                        String user_name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String user_profile=c.getString(TAG_PROFILE);
                        String user_image=c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                        String user_cast=c.getString(TAG_CAST);
                        String user_age=c.getString(TAG_AGE);
                        String user_location=c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);



                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_NAME,user_name);
                        map.put(TAG_PROFILE, user_profile);
                        map.put(TAG_IMAGE, user_image);
                        map.put(TAG_CAST, user_cast);
                        map.put(TAG_AGE, user_age+" years");
                        map.put(TAG_LOCATION, user_location);



                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        aList.add(map);


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            super.onPostExecute(file_url);
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread

                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */

                    // updating listview

                   CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),aList);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }

        }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to [AndroidQuery](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/detail?name=android-query-full.0.25.10.jar) with custom adapter :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listData;
    private AQuery aQuery;

    private static final String TAG_NAME="name";
    private static final String TAG_PROFILE="profile_id";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE="image";
    private static final String TAG_CAST="cast";
    private static final String TAG_AGE="age";
    private static final String TAG_LOCATION="location";


    public CustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listData=listData;
        aQuery = new AQuery(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder.propic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.propic);
            holder.txtproname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtproname);
            holder.txtproid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtproid);
            holder.txtprofilecast = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtprofilecast);
            holder.txtprofileage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtprofileage);
            holder.txtprofileplace = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtprofileplace);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtproname.setText(listData.get(position).get(TAG_NAME));
        holder.txtproid.setText(listData.get(position).get(TAG_PROFILE));
        holder.txtprofilecast.setText(listData.get(position).get(TAG_CAST));
        holder.txtprofileage.setText(listData.get(position).get(TAG_AGE));
        holder.txtprofileplace.setText(listData.get(position).get(TAG_LOCATION));

        aQuery.id(holder.propic).image(listData.get(position).get(TAG_IMAGE),true,true,0,R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        // image parameter : 1 : memory cache,2:file cache,3:target width,4:fallback image
        return convertView;
    }
    class ViewHolder{
        ImageView propic;
        TextView txtproname;
        TextView txtproid;
        TextView txtprofilecast;
        TextView txtprofileage;
        TextView txtprofileplace;
    }
}
```

How to set adapter to ListView  :

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),aList);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use universal image loader for viewing images from your server.Z
Just pass the image url and your view and you are good to go.

For your reference here is the link to Universal Image loader with all its documentation.
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Hop it helps you.

Comment: can you tell how to use it?

Comment: there is a brief documentation on the mentioned url. You can refer that.

Answer (score 0):

I am hardly suggest you to use Android Query for this. Its mind blowing api given by Android itself. You can download image, download bitmap or whatever you wanna do you can.
You can download the jar file from here :[here](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list) Download the jar file and set jar to your Build Path.

```
AQuery androidAQuery=new AQuery(this);
```

As an example to load image directly from url:

```
androidAQuery.id(YOUR IMAGEVIEW).image(YOUR IMAGE TO LOAD, true, true, getDeviceWidth(), ANY DEFAULT IMAGE YOU WANT TO SHOW);
```

As an example to get Bitmap from url:

```
androidAQuery.ajax(YOUR IMAGE URL,Bitmap.class,0,new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>(){
                        @Override
                        public void callback(String url, Bitmap object, AjaxStatus status) {
                            super.callback(url, object, status);

                            //You will get Bitmap from object.
                        }

                    });
```

It's very fast and accurate, and using this you can find many more features like Animation when loading; getting a bitmap, if needed; etc.

```
//Declare adapter globally.
private EfficientAdapter adapter;
//Initialize it in onCreate() method
adapter = new EfficientAdapter(this);
//Set your adapter like
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
//Adapter class code



    private class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            private LayoutInflater mInflater;
            private Context context;

            public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
                mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                this.context = context;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return aList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                final ViewHolder holder;

                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR ITEM LAYOUT, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
                    holder.txtProfile = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtProfile);
                    holder.txtCast = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCast);
                    holder.txtAge = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAge);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                holder.txtName.setText(aList.get(position).get(TAG_NAME));
                holder.txtProfile.setText(aList.get(position).get(TAG_PROFILE));
                holder.txtCast.setText(aList.get(position).get(TAG_CAST));
                holder.txtAge.setText(aList.get(position).get(TAG_AGE));
                aQuery.id(holder.imgUser).image(data.get(position).get(TAG_IMAGE), true, true);
                return convertView;
            }

            class ViewHolder {
                TextView txtName;
                TextView txtProfile;
                TextView txtCast;
                TextView txtAge;
                ImageView imgUser;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In source code of SimpleAdapter:

```
private void bindView(int position, View view) {
        final Map dataSet = mData.get(position);
        if (dataSet == null) {
            return;
        }

        final ViewBinder binder = mViewBinder;
        final String[] from = mFrom;
        final int[] to = mTo;
        final int count = to.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View v = view.findViewById(to[i]);
            if (v != null) {
                final Object data = dataSet.get(from[i]);
                String text = data == null ? "" : data.toString();
                if (text == null) {
                    text = "";
                }

                boolean bound = false;
                if (binder != null) {
                    bound = binder.setViewValue(v, data, text);
                }

                if (!bound) {
                    if (v instanceof Checkable) {
                        if (data instanceof Boolean) {
                            ((Checkable) v).setChecked((Boolean) data);
                        } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
                            // Note: keep the instanceof TextView check at the bottom of these
                            // ifs since a lot of views are TextViews (e.g. CheckBoxes).
                            setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                        } else {
                            throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() +
                                    " should be bound to a Boolean, not a " +
                                    (data == null ? "<unknown type>" : data.getClass()));
                        }
                    } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
                        // Note: keep the instanceof TextView check at the bottom of these
                        // ifs since a lot of views are TextViews (e.g. CheckBoxes).
                        setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                    } else if (v instanceof ImageView) {
                        if (data instanceof Integer) {
                            setViewImage((ImageView) v, (Integer) data);                            
                        } else {
                            setViewImage((ImageView) v, text);
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() + " is not a " +
                                " view that can be bounds by this SimpleAdapter");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can see if your view is ImageView , the code will use the url String be the resId in

```
/**
 * Called by bindView() to set the image for an ImageView but only if
 * there is no existing ViewBinder or if the existing ViewBinder cannot
 * handle binding to an ImageView.
 *
 * By default, the value will be treated as an image resource. If the
 * value cannot be used as an image resource, the value is used as an
 * image Uri.
 *
 * This method is called instead of {@link #setViewImage(ImageView, int)}
 * if the supplied data is not an int or Integer.
 *
 * @param v ImageView to receive an image
 * @param value the value retrieved from the data set
 *
 * @see #setViewImage(ImageView, int) 
 */
public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String value) {
    try {
        v.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(value));
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        v.setImageURI(Uri.parse(value));
    }
}
```

And your error is here , so you need Override the `getView` function of `SimpleAdapter`.Here is code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://gujjumatch.com/images/Girlnoimage.jpg");
image.setImageURI(uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create adapter and extend it to BaseAdapter and add all your items and call it in your AsyncTask's method and it will return your output as said by Haresh Chellana.

Comment: i found nice solution.