# Refreshing list view with affecting the view of the current position

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

In my app ,

i am downloading image one by one , for each image is downloaded and i will update item in the list view. Currently when i downloading some images, each image is downloaded and each will update or refresh the list view. For each refreshing, the visible portion of an item in the list view is automatically moving to first item. What i needed, suppose i watching the image 3 and image4 is downloaded and refreshing the list view now it will moved to first position but i need visible portion remains same what i seen before refreshing the listview (i.e., image 3should be in display portion).  I am refreshing the list view like

```
 CustomAdapterClass adapter = new CustomAdapterClass(context,lstOfDishes);       
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

can anyone suggest some ideas to clear my problems.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Instead downloading image manual use AndroidQuery async image downloading library check example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923853/how-to-fetch-the-image-using-json-in-listfragment/26924276#26924276

Comment: use http://square.github.io/picasso/ lib for image download from net

Answer (score 0):

use `adapter.notifyDataSetChange();` method to update the list adapter. do not create the adapter again and set it to list.

Answer (score 0):

first tiem u create adapter like this

```
CustomAdapterClass adapter = new CustomAdapterClass(context,lstOfDishes);       
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

if u added any value in your array Like (lstOfDishes) than u call This

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChange();
```

Comment: sorry to interrupt u, i am getting image from thread concept it is continuous running background for all other images, how to find the first item in listview

Comment: in thred call adapter.notifyDataSetChange();