# Error about "Load image from external Android to GridView with Asyntask"

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask

I want to load Image to GridView with Asyntask (speed up). But my app load about 1 2 image --> is stop . How can i fix it?

```
    class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ....
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grib_item,null);
            holder.imgView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.imgView.setTag(filepath[position]);

        new BitmapWorkerTask().execute(holder.imgView);
        return convertView;
    }
    class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imgView;
    }
}
```

Here my class BitmapWokerTask. .......................................................................................................................

```
 public class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

    private ImageView imv;
    private String path;



    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
        imv = (ImageView)params[0];
        path = imv.getTag().toString();

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        imv.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(path));

        return bitmap;
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (!imv.getTag().toString().equals(path)) {
            /* The path is not same. This means that this
                  image view is handled by some other async task. 
                  We don't do anything and return. */
            return;
        }

        if(result != null && imv != null){
            imv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imv.setImageBitmap(result);
        }else{
            imv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    public Bitmap decodeFile(String path){
        try {
            Log.d("111111111111","1111111111111111111");
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >=REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;
            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
 }
```

Here my logcat . seem error in doInBackground

```
12-11 11:20:51.835: E/AndroidRuntime(16737): Process: com.example.demolibraryayn, PID: 16737
12-11 11:20:51.835: E/AndroidRuntime(16737): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-11 11:20:51.835: E/AndroidRuntime(16737):    at   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
12-11 11:20:51.835: E/AndroidRuntime(16737):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
```

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923853/how-to-fetch-the-image-using-json-in-listfragment/26924276#26924276

Comment: you cannot use ui components inside doinbackground of async task. try doing it from onpostexecute of async task.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just change your code

```
 new BitmapWorkerTask(holder.imgView,filepath[position]).execute();
```

and change async task like this;

```
 public class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

private ImageView imv;
private String path;
Bitmap bitmap = null;
  public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imv,String path){
  this.path=path;
  this.imv=imv;
}


// Decode image in background.
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {


   bitmap=decodeFile(path);

    return bitmap;
}

// Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    if (!imv.getTag().toString().equals(path)) {
        /* The path is not same. This means that this
              image view is handled by some other async task. 
              We don't do anything and return. */
        return;
    }


    if(/*result != null && */imv != null){
        imv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  //    imv.setImageBitmap(result);
        imv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }else{
        imv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

public Bitmap decodeFile(String path){
    try {
        Log.d("111111111111","1111111111111111111");
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >=REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale *= 2;
        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: tks bro. I have a question. I have a Button when i click it, change Gridview to ListView . How can I do it effective.

Comment: My solution :I create ListAdapter class as GridAdaper class. when i click Button , setContentView(R.layout. ) to change layout. Do U think about this?

Comment: you can use both GridView and ListView in same layout (one's visibility is gone and other's is visible). but create separate adapters for both. accordingly set adapters to your both views. when a Button is clicked, just make visibility of one view **VISIBLE** and make visibility of other view **GONE**. hope this helps u