# GridView using Universal Image Loader not showing items & adapter getView method only called w/ position 0

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter, universal-image-loader, android-viewholder

I'm trying to create a gridview for favorite images using Universal Image Loader. Currently, no images appear or load. Likewise, my debugging has also found that getView is only called with position == 0. Please help!

Below I list:

1. The fragment code snippets that create the dummy arraylist and the custom adapter
2. The xml layout file of the fragment
3. The custom adapter that uses Universal Image Loader and a viewholder that holds a relativelayout w/ an imageView inside.
4. The xml layout file of the item for the gridview/viewholder.

   1. FavoritesFragment.java:

   public class FavoritesFragment extends Fragment {

   ```
   private GridView gridView;
   private Button imageButton;
   private FavoritesImageAdapter favoritesImageAdapter;
   ```

...

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<String> exampleUrls = new ArrayList<String>(); //Used for testing
        exampleUrls.add("http://i.imgur.com/gOD1PVH.jpg");
        exampleUrls.add("http://i.imgur.com/HB6wZox.jpg");
        exampleUrls.add("http://i.imgur.com/gOD1PVH.jpg");
        exampleUrls.add("http://i.imgur.com/HB6wZox.jpg");
        exampleUrls.add("http://i.imgur.com/HB6wZox.jpg");
        exampleUrls.add("http://i.imgur.com/gOD1PVH.jpg");

        favoritesImageAdapter = new FavoritesImageAdapter(getActivity(), 0, exampleUrls);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true); // Allows the fragment to change the menu buttons


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorites, container, false);
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        gridView.setAdapter(favoritesImageAdapter);
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Favorites");
        return view;
    }
}
```

2. fragment_favorites.xml:

   ```
   <GridView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/gridView"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:numColumns="3"
       android:background="@color/blue_200"
       android:layout_above="@+id/favoritesButtonLayout"/>

   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:paddingBottom="10px"
       android:id="@+id/favoritesButtonLayout">

       <Space
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       <ImageButton
           android:layout_weight="10"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/imageButton"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera"/>

       <Space
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       <ImageButton
           android:layout_weight="10"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/videoButton"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_action_video"/>

       <Space
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </LinearLayout>


   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/onboardingFavoritesImageView"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
   ```
3. FavoritesImageAdapter.java:

   public class FavoritesImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

   ```
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
   private Context mContext;
   private ArrayList<String> imageUrls;
   private ImageLoader imageLoader;
   DisplayImageOptions options;

   public FavoritesImageAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> urls){
       layoutInflater = layoutInflater.from(context);
       mContext = context;
       this.imageUrls = urls;
       imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
       options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
               .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
               .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
               .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
               .cacheOnDisk(true)
               .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
               .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
               .considerExifParams(true)
               .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
               .build();
   }




   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       Log.d("howmany", ""+imageUrls.size());
       return imageUrls.size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
       return imageUrls.get(position);
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return position;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       final FavoritesImageViewHolder favoritesImageViewHolder;
       final String url = (String)getItem(position); //TODO If the cast works delete this TODO

       if(convertView == null){
           RelativeLayout rootView = (RelativeLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_favorites_image, parent, false);
           favoritesImageViewHolder = FavoritesImageViewHolder.create(rootView);
           rootView.setTag(favoritesImageViewHolder);
       }
       else{
           favoritesImageViewHolder = (FavoritesImageViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }

       imageLoader.displayImage((String)getItem(position), favoritesImageViewHolder.imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {//TODO If the cast works delete this TODO
                   @Override
                   public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                       //holder.progressBar.setProgress(0);
                       //holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       Log.d("doesthishappen", "yes0");
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                                 FailReason failReason) {
                       //holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       Log.d("doesthishappen", "yes1");
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                       //holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       Log.d("doesthishappen", "yes2");
                   }
               }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current,
                                                int total) {
                       //holder.progressBar.setProgress(Math.round(100.0f * current / total));
                   }
               }
       );

       return favoritesImageViewHolder.rootView;

   }



   /**
    * ViewHolder's allow for a single object to maintain a Goal row item, so that the row item
    * doesn't have to create each individual component (textview layout etc.) each time the
    * row object is created/recreated. Allows for fast scrolling with little latency.
    */
   private static class FavoritesImageViewHolder {
       public final RelativeLayout rootView;
       public final ImageView imageView;


       private FavoritesImageViewHolder(RelativeLayout rootView, ImageView imageView) {
           this.rootView = rootView;
           this.imageView = imageView;
       }

       public static FavoritesImageViewHolder create(RelativeLayout rootView){
           ImageView imageView = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.favoritesMediaView);
           return new FavoritesImageViewHolder(rootView, imageView);
       }
   }
   ```

   }
4. item_grid_favorites_image.xml:

   ```
   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/favoritesMediaView"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
   ```

I'm not sure why this is happening. I know that all 6 fake urls are being passed to the adapter, and I do know that the getView method is called 6 times. I also know that Universal Image Loader never reaches the onLoadingComplete() callback method, but it does call onLoadingStarted() 6 times. All of these 6 times use position 0 of the arraylist. Please help, I hope to get better at android through this side project. Also, I apologize for the code formatting errors at the beginning. I tried to fix it, but it would not work.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923853/how-to-fetch-the-image-using-json-in-listfragment/26924276#26924276

Comment: I checked, thank you for the tip about android query. I wish I knew it existed. However, your answer in that thread doesn't change anything aside from replacing UIL w/ android query, which doesn't fix the fact that it will load position 0 6 times rather than loading position's 0-5. Likewise, I'm skeptical that replacing android query will make my images show up, because I don't think universal image loader was the problem. I think I made a bug, but I cannot seem to find it. Specifically, I think it has to do with the UI gridView component, but I don't know for sure. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

@eduardowarded: What i am observing is you are using [Holder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) for fast scrolling . What i can suggest you to add new property in  FavoritesImageViewHolder as int position. In getVirew method you have to assign favoritesImageViewHolder.position = position. And to access position you should use favoritesImageViewHolder.position.
This type of issues come because while scrolling the list `getView` will be called and its not syncronized which leads to threads updating the values.

I hope this will help you in resolving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it can help you

```
if(convertView == null){
    RelativeLayout rootView = (RelativeLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_favorites_image, parent, false);
    favoritesImageViewHolder = FavoritesImageViewHolder.create(rootView);
    rootView.setTag(favoritesImageViewHolder);
//add this code to your adapter
favoritesImageViewHolder.imageView.setTag(position);
}
```

Comment: So Thanks, Can u do it with PACASA lib :

Comment: see my answer below, it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the answer. I should have a item_grid_favorites_image.xml that is essentially identical to this one: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/sample/res/layout/item_grid_image.xml

If you would like to know how this works:

Before, I was using a item_grid_favorites_image.xml with a relative layout that had fill_parent height which caused universal image loader to take forever to load the picture. Also, this is why onLoadingStarted() was called 6 times, but onLoadingComplete() was called 0 times. It just got held up with loading time.

TIL I'm an idiot